# how to covert the jquery ajax reques to angular http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to convert old javascript ajax call to angular by using `$http` method in Angular.

My old one is like

```
var payload ={'id':'id-abc'}

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'myurl/com',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: payload,
    success: function (returndata) {
        //parse returndata 
     });
 });
```

in Angular way,

```
 $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: ‘myurl/com’,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: payload
    }).then(function(returndata) {
         console.log(returndata);
    })
```

The angular way gave me

```
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. Issue.
```

If I mimic the old way and setup the content-type header like

```
 $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: ‘myurl/com’,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: payload,
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }     
  }).then(function(returndata) {
       console.log(returndata);
  })
```

The server response is saying I am missing a params (it doesn’t).

I don’t have the control on the server side so I am not sure how to covert the old `$ajax` request to the new Angular one. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can start at the AngularJS official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http default is to serialze data as json

To send form encoded you need to use [`$httpParamSerializerJQLike`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) which also needs to be injected wherever you use it

```
$http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });
```

You could also set up global defaults for the header and a $httpInterceptor to do this transform instead of putting in each individual request

Comment: Thanks but we are using angular 1.3 and it seems like $httpParamSerializerJQLike is not supported. :(

Comment: are you using jQuery? If so can use $.param. Otherwise you'll have to write own serializer or switch back end. Shouldn't be hard to find a serializer either

Comment: Seems like $.param(object) is the way to solve it. thanks